# How to renew an object in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I have the following code:

```
   vector<SomeClass> objs;
   SomeClass obj;  // create a new obj with a new name
   objs.push_back(obj);

   while (someConditionIsTrue()){
       use(&obj);
       obj = new SomeClass(); // create a new obj with an existing name
       objs.pushback(obj)
   }
```

in this code `new SomeClass();` is in java OOP form - and is not a c++ code. what code should be used instead of `obj = new SomeClass();`?

Comment: Does your code compile? `obj` looks like it exists on the stack, whereas `new SomeClass()` will create the new instance on the heap, and your `objs` vector doesn't look like it stores pointers. Your code looks like it will leak memory and make excessive use of `SomeClass`'s copy-constructor.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Use a reference or a pointer of `SomeClass` for `obj`.

Comment: std::vector has no pushback function but it has push_back

Comment: It's very difficult to answer a question when you haven't bothered to explain what it is you're trying to do. "What code should I use if I want to do something I'm not going to tell you about?" is not an actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

```
obj = SomeClass();
```

`new SomeClass()` will return pointer to SomeClass object. You cannot assign it to varible `obj`, which type is `SomeClass`, not `SomeClass*`.

EDIT: If I remember well, `SomeClass obj();` should also work.

Comment: Just need to make sure there's a proper copy assignment operator.

Comment: I think it will work even with default copy assignment operator. The only way to make it doesn't work is to 'delete' copy assignment operator.
EDIT: I'm not sure and have no posiibility to test it, but just `SomeClass obj();` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanted is something like that:

```
vector<SomeClass *> objs;
SomeClass* obj = new SomeClass;  // create a new obj with a new name
objs.push_back(obj);

while (someConditionIsTrue())
{
  use(&obj);
  obj = new SomeClass; // create a new obj with an existing name
  objs.push_back(obj)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you were downvoted, because this is more or less the correct version of OP's code. Except you'll need `vector<SomeClass *> objs` instead.

Comment: Hehe, I'm wondering as well. Thanks for spotting the mistake in the code. I have missed that one.

Comment: 1) The code was incorrect before the edit; 2) This is just asking for memory leaks... It's not the kind of answer you should suggest to new C++ users imo. Just put the SomeClasses directly in the vector, or use shared_ptrs.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of the language is somewhat off. Here is your code as annotated:

```
vector<SomeClass> objs;
SomeClass obj;  // create a new obj with a new name
objs.push_back(obj);

while (someConditionIsTrue()){
    use(&obj);
    obj = new SomeClass(); // create a new obj with an existing name
    objs.pushback(obj)
 }
```

Here is what ACTUALLY happens

```
// create an object called "objs" which is a std::vector header, on the stack.
vector<SomeClass> objs;
// create an instace of "SomeClass" on the stack, call it obj.
SomeClass obj;
// allocate storage in the heap for some number of SomeClass instances to
// act as the storage for "objs", and assign them to it's "m_data" member.
// default construct the first one,
// then call it's copy constructor with the stack instance of "Obj" to
// copy the values/data into the first entry of the heap allocation of objs. 
objs.push_back(obj);

while (someConditionIsTrue()){
   // pass a pointer to the stack-allocated instance of obj.
   use(&obj);
   // create a new instance of "SomeClass" on the heap,
   // default/zero construct it,
   // return the pointer to this heap allocation and pass it
   // to obj.operator=(const SomeClass*) to copy the data into
   // the stack space allocated for "obj".
   obj = new SomeClass(); // create a new obj with an existing name
   // leak the pointer to the previous heap allocation by not storing it.

   // increase the size of the heap allocation backing objs and then
   // default construct the first SomeClass instance in the new space,
   // then copy our freshly copy-initialized stack instance back into it.
   objs.pushback(obj)
}
```

You could write this code numerous other ways, but it seems like the most sensible would be.

```
std::vector<SomeClass> objs;

while (someConditionIsTrue()) {
    objs.resize(objs.size() + 1); // grow me a new element.
    use(&objs.back());
}
```

Or make "use" take a reference.

```
void use(SomeClass& obj);
//...
    use(objs.back());
```

If you really want a local object to try the entry.

```
while (someConditionIsTrue()) {
    objs.resize(objs.size() + 1);
    // the compiler will either optimize this out entirely,
    // or use a pointer under the hood.
    SomeClass& obj = objs.back();
    use(&obj); // take the address of the object obj references.
}
```

Also, be aware that "resize()" can get expensive. You might want to do this upfront:

```
objs.reserve(1024); // or something you know is likely to cover most use cases.
```

If you really, really have to use a pointer.

```
SomeClass* obj = nullptr;

while (someConditionIsTrue()) {
    objs.resize(objs.size() + 1);
    obj = &objs.back();
    use(obj);
}
```

Instead of "objs.resize()" you may be able to use placement-new with a ctor:

```
    objs.emplace_back(SomeClass());
```

Others have suggested that you use

```
obj = Someclass();
```

But note that this is copying a default-constructed stack copy of the object.

```
{
    SomeClass tempObj;
    obj.operator=(std::move(tempObj));
}
```

I don't think that's what you actually want to do. It's more expensive than just having a stack-local copy like this:

```
while (someCondition()) {
    SomeClass stackCopy;
    ...
}
```

the compiler is smart enough not to give up the stack space each loop. What it will do is a thing called "Placement new" to re-invoke the constructor on the same object:

```
SomeClass obj;

while (someCondition()) {
     new (&obj) SomeClass(); // Call SomeClass() ctor on the memory at &obj
     ...
}
```

But - this is basically how the compiler achieved my previous code sample.